# Sacrificial meat and pets

Tags: fiqh, sunni, sacrifice

What is the ruling regarding feeding your pet (cat) with sacrificial meat. What about stray dogs?

Comment: It certainly would be better to feed it to needy people. There are people who will accept even trotters and offal.

Answer (score 1):

The basic of a sacrifice is that the offered sacrifice animal is halal and has been sacrificed (slaughtered) in a halal manner.

It is certainly better if you feed it to people (for details see for example [What is the basis for giving meat of qurbani as a gift to relatives and friends?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49591/what-is-the-basis-for-giving-meat-of-qurbani-as-a-gift-to-relatives-and-friends)), but it doesn't harm if animals ate from it once the sheep or cow or camel you have sacrificed was slaughtered. See also this fatwas on islamweb #[130037](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/130037) and #[183747](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/183747) both in Arabic language.

The prophet () said in a long hadith:

> ... there is a reward for service to every living animal."
> (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/42/11) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/210))

And we have a lots of ahadith saying that it is a good deed to be kind and feed animals:

- > "A woman entered the (Hell) Fire because of a cat which she had tied, neither giving it food nor setting it free to eat from the vermin of the earth. "
  > (See in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/124), while imam Muslim reported longer versions of this see for example [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/10/11))
- > There was a dog moving around a well whom thirst would have killed. Suddenly a prostitute from the prostitutes of Bani Isra'il happened to see it and she drew water in her shoe and made it drink, and she was pardoned because of this.
  > (See in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/134) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/212))
- > "The merciful are shown mercy by Ar-Rahman. Be merciful on the earth, and you will be shown mercy from Who is above the heavens. The womb is named after Ar-Rahman, so whoever connects it, Allah connects him, and whoever severs it, Allah severs him."
  > (See for example in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/30))

Comment: Jazakallah, to be on the safe side i only give the scarp meat/fat of the sacrificial animal to my cat.